# ROR : can you configure an exception handler on a per controller basis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ROR project I have a controller in which I want to always catch exceptions to do some cleanup before the error is propagated back up to the caller.  Can this be done in ROR?  I want a hook that will be called when any exception is encountered in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html):

```
  class WhateverController < ApplicationController
      rescue_from Exception do |exception|
        # whatever handling here
      end

      # ...
    end
```

Comment: Can you then re-throw the exception to the standard 500 error page?

Comment: Yes, you can rethrow an exception in ruby by calling `raise`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `around_filter`.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  around_filter :custom_handle_exception

  def show
    # ...
  end

  private

  def custom_handle_exception
    yield
  rescue StandardError => e
    handle_the_error(e)
    raise e
  end

end
```

You can also do something similar with the `rescue_from` class method.

You should typically not rescue *every* exception. Exceptions inheriting [`StandardError`](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) should be fine to rescue, though.